# Wrapper class in Http getmethod

Tags: class, http, wrapper-class

below is my code
Created a wrapper class like below

```
public class ResponseWrapper{
    public list<Account> lstaccounts;
    public boolean isError ;
    public string errorCode;
    public integer statusCode;
       public ResponseWrapper(){
         lstaccounts = new list<Account>();
         isError= false;
    }

}
```

and returning the wrapper class in the Httpget method

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/accounts/*')
global with sharing class AccountRestService {
@HttpGet
global static ResponseWrapper getAccounts() {
    ResponseWrapper resWrap = new ResponseWrapper();
    List<Account> accounts;

    try {
        accounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
        res.lstaccounts = accounts;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        resWrap.isError = true;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage()) = resWrap.errorCode;
        res.statusCode = 500 = resWrap.statusCode;
    }

    return resWrap;
  }
}
```

but its throwing the Error message 
Error: Compile Error: global methods do not support return type of ResponseWrapper at line 4 column 31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global methods must return global data types. You need to declare your class as global in order to use it as a return value.

As a side note, there's no point to your try-catch block here, because there's no exception you can possibly catch.

Also, you can chain assignments, but the value you're assigning must be on the far right:

```
    res.statusCode = resWrap.statusCode = 500;
```